# Can't set up HP Smart Array P410 in RAID 5 mode

Tags: raid, hp

I'm struggling to set up my HP Proliant MicroServer Gen10 along a second hand HP Smart Array P410. My plan is to use my 3 HDDs (same model, same size) in RAID 5 using the forementioned controller board.
I've tried to run HP's Smart Storage from an USB but it boots up to a white screen with HP's logo and that's all.
I had no luck using any of the FX keys from F5 to F12, I never enter in any of the utilities that are mentioned in google or the BIOS of the raid controller. If I type "RAID" in the built-in EFI shell, I can get into the on-chip RAID controller, but I'm not interested on it since it doesn't support RAID 5.
I've tried to use ssacli from my Fedora and even from a live Ubuntu but it always says that only RAID 0 is available (take a look at the attached screenshot). I'm desperate and I have no more ideas about this thing, does anyone had this kind of problems? Am I missing something?

The image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/QhDD5VFkEd7CQeAE7

Thanks for any help!
/Felipe

Comment: I would ask this question on the HPE forum. My first guess is a license issue.

Comment: Can I also suggest that you don't use R5 anyway, for large HDD's it's been abandoned for over a decade now by storage professionals. It's actually very dangerous in those situations, we have someone come to serverfault every few weeks saying 'help me recover my data from my R5 array' - inevitably we have to tell them to restore from last backup. If you're using small (<1TB) SSDs with high write-wearing/MTBF and low write-failure stats then sure, maybe - if you're using consumer HDD's then it's a matter of when, not if, you lose data - try to use R1/10 or R6/60

Comment: Oh and this is an old, but still valid and easy to read, article on why - https://www.zdnet.com/article/why-raid-5-stops-working-in-2009/

Answer (score 2):

This card has a poorly documented HBA mode, which is not supported by HPE nor in the Linux kernel (without custom out of tree patches), and it looks like the previous owner may have switched this card into that mode. The normal HPE utilities cannot turn this card's HBA mode on or off and the card will always report HBA mode as not supported, even when it's active.

You'll need a third party tool [hpsahba](https://github.com/im-0/hpsahba) to check the actual status of HBA mode on the card, and to disable it if it is enabled.

For example:

Card info:

```
hpsahba -i /dev/sg1
```

Disable HBA mode:

```
hpsahba -d /dev/sg1
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the HPE Proliant MicroServer Gen10, it looks like you need a compatible Gen10 RAID controller card.

As per the quickspecs, you will need to install HPE Smart Array E208i-p SR Gen10 Controller. This controller supports RAID 5. Also, you will need to set server to boot in UEFI mode.

The part number to order for the controller is 804394-B21.

[Partsurfer link](https://partsurfer.hpe.com/Search.aspx?searchText=804394-B21)

[HPE Proliant MicroServer Gen10 Quickspecs](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/getdocument.aspx?docname=a00073554enw#)

[HPE Smart Array E208i-p SR Gen10 Controller Quickspecs](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=a00008187enw#)